# Why was Date.getTimezoneOffset deprecated?

Tags: java, date, timezone, utc

The documentation for [Date.getTimezoneOffset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTimezoneOffset%28%29) says:

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by
>   -(Calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + Calendar.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)) / (60 * 1000).

Why was it deprecated? Is there a shorter way (Apache Commons?) to get the offset from UTC in hours/minutes? I have a Date object ... should I convert it to JodaDate for this?

And before you ask why I want the UTC offset - it's just to log it, nothing more.

Comment: You should switch to JodaTime for anything related to Date and Time handling in Java IMHO.

Comment: Because not every timezone offset is an integer.  In other words, not every timezone is an hour earlier or later than the adjacent time zone.  Check out http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - it returns minutes, not hours.

Comment: @pcalcao - I have a `Date` object from an API I don't control. I can't "switch it to JodaTime". I can take the Date object, wrap it as a JodaTime object, and use that ... I suggested this as a possible answer.

Comment: @ripper234: Oops.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 questions here.

1. Why was Date.getTimezoneOffset deprecated?

I think it is because they actually deprecated nearly all methods of Date and moved their logic to calendar. We are expected to use generic `set` and `get` with the parameter that says which specific field we need. This approach has some advantages: less number of methods and the ability to run setters in a loop passing a different field each time. I personally used this technique a lot: it makes code shorter and easier to maintain.

2. Shortcut? But what's wrong with call

`Calendar.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)`  comparing to
`Calendar.getTimeZoneOffset()`

As far as I can see the difference is 6 characters.

Joda is a very strong library and if you really have to write a lot of sophisticated date manipulation code switch to it. I personally use the standard `java.util.Calendar` and don't see any reason to use external libraries: good old calendar is good enough for me.

Comment: I'll accept this for `they actually deprecated all methods of Date `. Everyone recommending I switch to joda - chill please, it's a date object in an API I'm using, I can't really change the API now, can I.

Answer (score 3):

All of the date manipulation logic was moved out of `Date` once the Java implementers realized that it might need to be implemented differently for different types of calendars (hence the need to use a `GregorianCalendar` to retrieve this info now). A `Date` is now just a wrapper around a UTC time value.

Answer (score 2):

Take care before you paste code from this page.
Perhaps just me but I believe that in order to get the tz offset in minutes you need to do

```
int tzOffsetMin = (cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET))/(1000*60);
```

rather than what the Javadoc says, which is:

```
int tzOffsetMin = -(cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET))/(1000*60);
```

`Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET` gives you the standard offset (in msecs) from UTC. This doesn't change with DST. For example for US East Coast timezone this field will always be -6 hours regardless of DST.

`Calendar.DST_OFFSET` gives you the current DST offset (in msecs) - if any. For example during summer in a country that uses DST this field is likely to have the value +1 hour (1000*60*60 msecs).