# If Date.getTimezoneOffset is deprecated in Java, what about JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

The reasons for deprecation in Java are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10486471/12570).

Doesn't the same reasoning apply for Javascript?

[I understand the difference between Java and JavaScript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it does return minutes, not hours.  So it *can* represent offsets correctly.

But its recently come to my attention that it is horribly broken, thanks to a bad decision in the ECMAScript 5.1 spec.  See [JavaScript Time Zone is wrong for past Daylight Saving Time transition rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946002/javascript-time-zone-is-wrong-for-past-daylight-saving-time-transition-rules)

so I wouldn't rely on it anyway.  No great solution yet, but watch this space.  I will update this answer as I learn more.